# Numbering multiple dates per delivery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am interested in producing the following view where different delivery dates are numbered.

```
SalesID    Delivery Date DateNo
SO00000014 2014-02-21    1
SO00000015 2014-02-13    1
SO00000016 2014-01-28    1
SO00000017 2014-03-17    1
SO00000018 2014-02-13    1
SO00000020 2014-03-19    1
SO00000020 2014-03-20    2
SO00000020 2014-03-21    3
```

My question is how to number different dates associated to a single SalesId like in the 
 SO00000020 above. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Each record would contain the total number of sales per sales person up to that point?

Comment: Only you can really answer your own question.  What column combinations require a unique result that consumers (applications, etc.) and business demand?  `SalesID + DateNo`? `SalesID + Delivery Date + DateNo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not knowing your data, the view definition would be:

```
SELECT
    [SalesID],
    [Delivery Date],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SalesID] ORDER BY [Delivery Date]) AS DateNo
FROM
    [WhatEverTable]
```

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

`ROW_NUMBER()` by itself will return a running count of the rows, but when you add the `OVER(PARTITION BY [SalesID] ORDER BY [Delivery Date])` it gives a running count **per sales id**, ordered by the date.

Does that make sense?

EDIT: If you do make this a view, just be aware that the results will be filtered by your WHERE clause. Using your data above, if you queried for sales that occurred after 2014-03-20, SalesID SO00000020 will only have a single entry for 2014-03-21 with a DateNo of 1.

If you need the data to persist regardless of the WHERE clause, you will likely just have to scrap the idea of a view and get creative with the query that accesses the data.

Comment: Excellent Mark, that's it. Thanks! I was fiddling with row_number but I couldn't get it right.

Comment: Glad I could help! Make sure to mark this as answered so others know this worked for you.

Comment: Where do I mark this as answered? I don't have a full account yet. Would that hold me back from marking it as answered?

Comment: To the left of the answer (just under the vote count) you should see a grey check mark, just click it to mark this question as answered.

Comment: As an additional note, check out this quick video if you are interested in the power of the other windowing functions: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/refactoring-t-sql-windowing-functions/

Comment: If you turn your query there into a sub-select then you don't need to worry about filtering...

Comment: I would imagine that being fairly IO intensive, but would be interested to see it posted as an answer.